# Dynamically setting the SPA source path in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, single-page-application, .net-core-3.1

I have a .Net Core 3.1 application that I use as an API but it also serves my SPA (Angular). As of recently I am having some issues with SEO so I would like to serve a static version of my Angular application when Googlebot comes around.

Is here any way to dynamically set the SPA source path?

```html
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
});
```

Currently I have a small middleware file where I detect Googlebot based on the UserAgent string. Then I pass that through the request.

```html
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    var userAgent = context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
    context.Items["isCrawler"] = userAgent.Contains("Googlebot");
    await _next(context);
}
```

But I cannot access the Request in the Configure() method in the Startup.cs file. Is there anyway how I can make this work? I really want to be able to dynamically set the SourcePath.

Thanks a lot!

Regards

Answer (score -1):

You can  try the following codes ,  putting the middleware in Configure（）method .

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
 
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                var userAgent = context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
                context.Items["isCrawler"] = userAgent.Contains("Googlebot");
                if ((bool)context.Items["isCrawler"])
                {
                    app.UseSpa(spa =>
                    {
                        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
                    });
                }
                else {
                    //do your stufff....
                }
                // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
                await next();
            });
     …}
```

Comment: I use the Middleware class to get a hold of the Request so I can determine the UserAgent. I did not yet find how to set the app spa settings inside of a middleware class, that would solve my issue!

Comment: Yes, you are right . I know you have used the Middleware class to get a hold of the Request. I mean you can try to put middleware in Configure（）method, like the sample code in document  is used to demonstrate creating a middleware component. Then you needn't  to  set the app spa settings inside of a middleware class. Of course, setting the app spa settings inside of a middleware class is another way.

Comment: Sadly I could not make it work. Once I move that code inside of the Middleware it breaks. Is there any way how I can check the request when processing the Configure method in the Startup class?

Comment: I edit my answer, hoping it can help you.

Comment: Yes! It is going the right direction! Using conditional middleware should do the trick (App.UseWhen). BUT there is also something in the ConfigureServices method that is setting the rootpath (AddSpaStaticFiles) that is maybe causing why it is not yet working.

Comment: Has your problem been solved?